# Importing an existing MySQL database into the first run of a Docker container

Tags: mysql, docker, express, docker-compose

I have a project with next structure:

```
- project 
   - backend
     ...
     Dockerfile
   docker-compose.yml
```

And I made a container with the following services (docker-compose.yml)

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  app:
    build: ./back
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: yummy
    ports:
      - 3307:3306
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
volumes:

  db_data:
```

When you run the docker-compose up --build command, it starts Node.js app on localhost:3000 and MySQL connection on localhost:3307.

(my Dockerfile for backend)

```
FROM node:latest

WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
CMD npm start
```

The applications work, but I have a ready-made database. It defines tables and some initial entries in the tables. Is it possible to download a file **dump.sql** with dump of my database when the container is first launched?

My questions:

1. How can I create a database according to my export file (**dump.sql**) when starting a container?
2. Will I need to run the database initialization script every time I start the container?
3. How to save changes that will be made when the container is running?

For example, I will initialize the database via a file, add new records to the tables and close the container. Then I'll open it again. Will I have to initialize the database again, and how can I retrieve the data created during the last run?

Comment: The docs are quite helpful - [Initializing a fresh instance](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql#:~:text=Initializing%20a%20fresh%20instance)